# Why is FALSE type-juggled to an empty string while TRUE is type-juggled to "1"?

Tags: php

Couldn't the string representation of FALSE be `"0"`, just like TRUE is juggled to `"1"`?

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

What do they mean by "allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values".
So `TRUE` does not allow that ?

CAn you explain that and give some examples please ?

NOTE: I Know there are other related questions, but none of them provided what i'm precisely looking for!! So don't bother copying a link!!

Comment: Yes, it could have been. But it wasn't, and it's too late to change now. The comment `This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.` is intended to apply to the entire previous sentence, not just the juggling of `FALSE` to `""`.

Comment: Because whoever came up with PHP thought that it would be great to be able to write `if(!$_GET['foo'])` and catch both the case when it's `null` _and_ `''`.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the following code:

```
var_dump("0" == false.""); // bool(false)
var_dump(""  == false.""); // bool(true)
```

If false would be represented as `"0"`, the given comparison would be `false` as `"0" != ""`.
This is the reason why `false` is represented as `""` instead of `"0"`, providing back conversion.

Comment: I like your interpretation, but I'm not sure it was the reason, because PHP never auto-converts boolean type to string in comparison operations. Furthermore `empty("0")` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is more or less opinion based. And here is my interpretation:

Historically PHP uses FALSE as an output value in many scenarios in case of unsuccessful operation. For instance `substr()` returns **string** or **FALSE**. Therefore, in my opinion, PHP optimized FALSE conversion **for output** purposes:

```
$name = 'JOHN';
$theSixthLetter = substr($name, 6, 1); // false
echo 'The sixth letter of the name is: ' . $theSixthLetter; // empty string
```